# How to execute result of a query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a view by joining two tables. These two tables have a few columns with the same name. Which gives an error

> SQL Error [42701]: ERROR: column "column_name" specified more than once

I cannot use column names while creating the view as there are 30+ columns and new columns will be added to both tables over the period of time. Hence, I have to use * to get all the columns.

Now, to eliminate columns which exist in both the table, I went ahead and did this:

```
SELECT 'SELECT ' || STRING_AGG('u2.' || column_name, ', ') || ' FROM schema_name.table_name u2' 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'table_name' 
  AND table_schema = 'schema_name' 
  AND column_name NOT IN ('column_name');
```

This gives me the query to select data from `schema_name.table_name` without the column column_name. Great!!

The problem: How do I execute the result of the above query?

I tried `PREPARE` statement, it is just executing the above query and not the result of the above query.

Also, creating a temporary table with no column "column_name" isn't a viable solution.

Comment: In `psql` you can run this using the `\gexec` meta command.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, after executing this query, I have to join the results with the other table to create a view

Comment: You will need to use PL/pgSQL and [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Comment: @TridevChaudhary Check my answer. I have also provided a db <> fiddle (DEMO) in my answer. You might need to modify the query according to your table names.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You saved me! I had too many partition tables to delete in one go so combining ```\gexec``` followed by the below sql code worked wonders!

```select 'drop table if exists "' || tablename || '" cascade;' from pg_tables; ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepare a dynamic query and then `EXECUTE` it. It would be something like this:

```sql
DO
$do$
    BEGIN

        EXECUTE (
            SELECT CONCAT('CREATE VIEW temp_view AS SELECT ',
                          -- SELECT table1 columns here
                          (SELECT STRING_AGG('u1.' || column_name, ', ')
                           FROM information_schema.columns
                           WHERE table_name = 'table1'
                             AND table_schema = 'schema_name'
                          -- AND column_name NOT IN ('column_name')  -- not omitting for table1
                          ),
                          ', ',
                           -- SELECT table2 columns here
                          (SELECT STRING_AGG('u2.' || column_name, ', ')
                           FROM information_schema.columns
                           WHERE table_name = 'table2'
                             AND table_schema = 'schema_name'
                             AND column_name NOT IN ('column_name')),
                           -- Dynamically prepare the FROM and JOIN clauses
                          ' FROM table1 u1 JOIN table2 u2 ON u1.id = u2.table1_id'));

    END
$do$;
```

**[CHECK DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3ba6e5c7d84056a757414f06b8ce2a53)**